# Where to ask Pegasus for a free earlier connection: transfer desk or gate?

Tags: connecting-flights, saw, pegasus-airlines

We're two people going Zurich-Istanbul-Ercan with Pegasus and picked the second tightest connection, since if we miss the tightest connection and the next one is full (that specific flight is usually full in June) then we have to sleep in the transit area, which the other person wouldn't like as it doesn't have anywhere comfortable to sleep.

I'm aware that you can sometimes get an earlier connection for free if asking ground staff.

My question is: assuming the inbound flight makes it in time, is it the transfer desk or the gate staff right before boarding that I should ask whether we could possibly be put on the earlier connecting flight?

We're only bringing hand luggage

Comment: If I were you, I'd try both.

Comment: If you only have a carry on , I would go to the gate as soon as possible. Depending on the airline policy, it is likely that you would either put on a standby or they would straight up issue you a boarding pass for an earlier flight.

Comment: @Jim Mackenzie You are right it would be completely based on the company policy, and possibly only on selected routes like you mentioned. I have asked to be on an earlier flight in other airlines too such as Lufthansa and Turkish Airlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Asked at the transfer desk and was put on the first connection. Just went up, showed our connecting boarding passes and IDs, and asked if they could please put us on the earlier flight. The agent asked if we had any checked bags (we didn't), worked on her computer for 5 minutes and printed new boarding passes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any checked bags or are you only travelling with a carry on? Based on my own experience travelling with Air Canada frequently between Ottawa-Toronto and Ottawa-Montreal, I am able to get on an earlier flight in most cases. I only have a carry-on though, I never check a bag. If you have a checked bag I would definitely ask it at the customer service transfer desk just because airline may need more time for logistics. If you don't have a checked bag, you could do either.

Comment: Carry-on only...

Comment: @Serguden These flights are part of Air Canada's Rapidair service, and feature same-day standby at no additional charge, so may not be comparable, necessarily, to other services.  (Air Canada charges for this on most other routes.)